# Viewport of nested svg doesn't work properly

Tags: css

I want to position nested SVG without margin.
In this situation, I can find out that there's too much margin, and if I decrease the height, the shape is disappeared. How can I solve this problem?

```
<svg width="300" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
        <svg>
          <line x1="10" x2="275" y1="100" y2="100" fill="grey"/>
        </svg>
        <svg>
          <line
            x1="10"
            x2="275"
            y1="100"
            y2="100"
            fill="green"
          />
        </svg>
      </svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<line>` elements are placed with some margins/padding due to their `x/y`  properties:

```
      <line x1="10" x2="275" y1="100" y2="100" fill="grey"/>
```

translates to:

- start the line at x=10 svg units;
- draw the line to x(2)=275.
  So you'll get a **left margin of 10** units and a **right margin of 25** units.

Besides the `<fill>` property won't have an effect on `<line>` elements.
You set stroke colors via `stroke` attribute.

If you need your nested svg to be stretched to the parent svg's width, you will also need to set
`preserveAspectRatio="none"` and `width:100%`:

```css
.svg-parent {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.svg-parent-responsive {
  width: 100%;
}

.line {
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke: #000;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}

.line-green {
  stroke: green;
}

.line-gray {
  stroke: gray;
}

.resize {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize">

  <svg class="svg-parent" width="300px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
    <svg>
      <line class="line line-gray" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="50" y2="50"  />
    </svg>
  <svg>
      <line class="line line-green" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="75" y2="75" />
    </svg>
  </svg>

  <svg class="svg-parent svg-parent-responsive" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100">
    <svg>
      <line class="line line-gray" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="50" y2="50"  />
    </svg>
  <svg>
      <line class="line line-green" x1="0" x2="100%" y1="75" y2="75" />
    </svg>
  </svg>

</div>
<p>Resize me</p>
```